# Divegent series test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this infinite series. What test would you use to show that it is divergent? I tried limit, ratio and tried to compare it with $2^{1/n}$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {2^{1/n}}-1.$$

Thanks

Comment: Can you find an asymptotic expansion of $2^{1/n}-1$?

Comment: I am not able to at the moment, trying

Comment: It shouldn't be this hard (?)

Comment: Can you think of an alternative way to write $2^{1/n}$ which may make seeing it easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$
2^{1/n}=\mathrm{e}^{\log 2/n}>1+\frac{\log 2}{n},
$$
and hence
$$
2^{1/n}-1>\frac{\log 2}{n},
$$
and using comparison test we obtain that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2^{1/n}-1)=\infty
$$